# Angular 2 Universal prerendering without Webpack

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-universal

I'd like the idea of serverside prerendering, with Angular Universal. The page loads faster, webcrawler can index them easier and you can provide previews of your Website.

But i've been working a long time with Webpack, and can say I hate it, because it's so complexe. (That's only my opinion, properbly there are a lot of developers who love Webpack).

Now my question: **Is it possible to use Angular Universal without Webpack, or are there any alternatives?**

What I am plan to use:

- ASP.NET Core
- VS 2017
- Typescript
- Angular 2
- Edge

Comment: Angular universal dont needs webpack you need only nodejs to serve your application and there is no alternative because your angularapp will run seperately and backend separately no matter which technology you are using for backend.

Comment: Webpack is only for development environment not for production mode

Comment: @BabarBilal Thanks, for the comment :). I know that webpack is a build tool, and it is only for development. But how can i implement Serverside Prerendering without using Webpack? Because in the documentation they alwas use Webpack.

Comment: AngularCLI support Universal now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked the angular team via GitHub, and SystemJs will also be supported. But not at the moment, because they are merging the Universal project into Angular Core.